# Setting correct endpoints for dbpedia in emacs-sparql

Tags: emacs, sparql, dbpedia

I am starting to use emacs [sparql-mode](https://github.com/ljos/sparql-mode) to edit and execute my sparql queries in scripts instead of in the browser.

My script, `test.sparql`, is as follows:

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

ENDPOINT <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>

SELECT DISTINCT ?Concept WHERE {
  [] a ?Concept
} LIMIT 5
```

However, when I execute this with `C-c C-c`, I keep getting:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Not Allowed
Server: nginx/1.4.7
Date: Tue, 15 Apr 2014 14:34:16 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 172
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.7</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Or when I change

```
ENDPOINT <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>
```

to

```
ENDPOINT <http://dbpedia.org/>
```

What is a correct endpoint for access that resembles http://dbpedia.org/snorql/ ?  And what modifications do I need to do to return results in JSON?

Comment: Is `endpoint` something specific to sparql-mode?  It's not part of SPARQL 1.1.  In SPARQL 1.1, you'd typically use the `service` keyword. See http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-federated-query-20130321/#service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used sparql-mode, but `endpoint` isn't part of the SPARQL syntax.  The `service` keyword is used to indicate federated query.  It's described more fully in [SPARQL 1.1 Federated Query](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-federated-query/), and there are examples.  I think that your query would be something along the lines of:

```
select distinct ?concept where {
  service <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> { 
    [] a ?concept
  }
}
limit 5
```

I'm not familiar with all the details, so I'm not sure about whether the remote endpoint gets the information about the `limit 5` or not, so it might be helpful to handle it with a subquery within the `service`:

```
select ?concept where {
  service <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> { 
    select distinct ?concept where {
      [] a ?concept
    }
    limit 5
  }
}
```

As I said, I don't have sparql-mode, but I can run that query with Jena's command line `sparql` tool, and I get the kind of results that one would expect.  (You might want to increase that `limit`, though;  the first five results I tend to get are things like:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| concept                                                             |
=======================================================================
| <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property>               |
| <http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#QuadMapFormat>           |
| <http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#QuadStorage>             |
| <http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#array-of-QuadMap>        |
| <http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#QuadMap>                 |
| <http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#array-of-QuadMapFormat>  |
```

which are not the useful DBpedia classes you're probably expecting.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no "ENDPOINT" in sparql or Emacs sparql-mode!
When you make it run by clicking "C-c C-c" there is a prompt in the mini-buffer
asking for a URL which will be the base endpoint! This base endpoint can be anything
like a fuseki server running on localhost or well "http://dbpedia.org/sparql"!
The format can also be specified after you give the url, and the default should be csv/txt!

If you want to change the endpoint you just have to click "C-c C-u" and supply the new URL.
you can as well change the format by clicking "C-c C-f"!
In case you forget the key-bindings you can always do "C-h m", where "h" stands for help and "m" stands for mode ;)

And here is your example running:

[image]